# how to set mysql root password in a chef cookbook?

Tags: mysql, ruby, vagrant, chef-infra

I am using this [mysql chef cookbook](https://github.com/chef-cookbooks/mysql/blob/master/libraries/helpers.rb). The cookbook is supposed to allow you to set the mysql root password. It does so through the following

```
    def init_records_script
      # Note: shell-escaping passwords in a SQL file may cause corruption - eg
      # mysql will read \& as &, but \% as \%. Just escape bare-minimum \ and '
      sql_escaped_password = root_password.gsub('\\') { '\\\\' }.gsub("'") { '\\\'' }
      Chef::Log.info("passxyz" + sql_escaped_password)
      <<-EOS
        set -e
        rm -rf /tmp/#{mysql_name}
        mkdir /tmp/#{mysql_name}

        cat > /tmp/#{mysql_name}/my.sql <<-'EOSQL'
UPDATE mysql.user SET #{password_column_name}=PASSWORD('#{root_password}')#{password_expired} WHERE user = 'root';
DELETE FROM mysql.user WHERE USER LIKE '';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
DELETE FROM mysql.db WHERE db LIKE 'test%';
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS test ;
EOSQL

       #{db_init}
       #{record_init}

       while [ ! -f #{pid_file} ] ; do sleep 1 ; done
       kill `cat #{pid_file}`
       while [ -f #{pid_file} ] ; do sleep 1 ; done

       EOS
    end
```

And

```
def record_init
      cmd = v56plus ? mysqld_bin : mysqld_safe_bin
      cmd << " --defaults-file=#{etc_dir}/my.cnf"
      cmd << " --init-file=/tmp/#{mysql_name}/my.sql"
      cmd << ' --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp' if v56plus
      cmd << ' &'
      return "scl enable #{scl_name} \"#{cmd}\"" if scl_package?
      cmd
    end
```

the above appears to be trying to execute a command:
`/usr/bin/mysqld_safe --defaults-file=/etc/mysql/my.cnf --init-file=/tmp/mysql/my.sql &` I tried looking for the file to inspect it but could not find it. So this does not seem to be working. Eventually, using this cookbook, the mysql root password end up no being set at all. Is there any obvious error above?  How do I debug it?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that [the chef resource](https://github.com/chef-cookbooks/mysql/pull/541/files) `bash` taking  `init_records_script` as input parameter needed the `user "root"` attribute. See this PR:
https://github.com/chef-cookbooks/mysql/pull/541